# Проблема в получении содержимого тега JQUERY

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Сайт на Wordpress
Пытаюсь получить содержимое тега на странице (он один на странице):

```
$('.amount').text();
```

но мне выдает сразу содержимое всех тегов со всех страниц в строчку.
Как мне работать именно с содержимым тега нужной мне страницы?

Так же я подумал, так как манипуляция с содержимым тега у меня должна быть одинакова для всех, то можно сделать как то так:

```
var Amounts = $('.amount').text();
$(Amounts).each(function(){
  var price = $(this).text().slice(-1,-5);
  console.log(price);
});
```

С таким вариантом, в консоли выдается ошибка : 
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
а ниже в строку содержимое тегов

Comment: Ошибка в коде. Переменная price всегда будет принимать значение последнего елемента.
`var Amounts = $('.amount').text();
var price = 0;
$(Amounts).each(function(){
   price += $(this).text().slice(-1,-5);
  console.log(price);
});`

Comment: @Rikaz Попробовал ваш код, в консоль выдается та же ошибка и тот же набор в строчку

Comment: покажите пример `html` и желаемый результат на выходе (можно отредактировать вопрос и дополнить). Некорректна строка: `var Amounts = $('.amount').text();` + `$(Amounts).each...` Вы передаёте в качестве селектора содержимое `.amount` (конечно, если у Вас в содержимом не другой селектор :)). Уберите text - `var Amounts = $('.amount');`. Да и не очень понятно, что Вы там со `slice()` пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: @Alexander   По сути задача в следующем - нужно взять содержимое тега .amount умножить это на число и результат вставить в другой тег.</br> http://xn--e1affqdacals3k.su/shop/uvs-tm-8/ - консоль посмотрите

Comment: @Роман тогда так: [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/4vnosm1h/). Если конечно `.amount` на странице встречается только один раз.

Comment: @Роман по вашей ссылке на странице 27 элементов с классом `.amount`. Неудивительно, что и результатов больше одного

Comment: @Роман Ну да. У вас там этого класса немало ) в моём примере поправьте `var amount = $('.single_add_to_cart_wrapper .amount').text();` Таким образом будет выбрана только цена, которая находиться в блоке `single_add_to_cart_wrapper `

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich Александр спасибо, очень всё тривиально оказалосью

Comment: ps. у Вас там ещё `руб.` в содержимом с ценой имеется. Можно воспользоваться `parseInt()`. Итого: `$("#result").text(parseInt(amount) * 5);`

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось в комментариях, автору требовалось взять содержимое из тега с классом `amount`, умножить полученное значение на число и вставить результат в другой тег.

Проблема заключалась в неправильной передачи селектора, а также в том, что на странице имелось несколько тегов с классом `amount`

Нужный тег `amount` находится в блоке с классом `single_add_to_cart_wrapper`, следовательно реализовать можно следующим образом:

```
var amount = $('.single_add_to_cart_wrapper .amount').text();
$("#result").text(parseInt(amount) * 5);
```

**ps.** в содержимом имеется, помимо цены, слово "**руб.**", следовательно умножение строки на число ни к чему не приведёт. Выручить может `parseInt()`